# Parsing split video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have video file split into few chunks. Split done and random file positions, but chunks are large enough.

I need to parse every part with different instances of AVFormatContext. Chunks come one after another in right order. I think there are two options here:

1. Being able to save and restore AVFormatContext state;
2. Save video file header (from first chunk) and attach it to every chunk.

I tried both but no success. First approach requires to go too deeply beyond public API of ffmpeg. With second approach I am unable to merge header with new chunk so that ffmpeg can handle it.

Can you help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on the file type. MP4 for example, the header must be completely rewritten, and can not just be copied. Flv the header can probably just be copied, but MUST be split on frame boundary and not randomly. TS could do this, but you would miss a frame at the cut point.

Realistically, the file will need to be reassembled, the split correctly.

Comment: I can save part of previous chunk for next chunk parsing. So we can assume that file split in proper way.

Comment: I see header copying is not a solution. Do you think it's better to save/restore AVFormatContext state?

Comment: Saving part of previous chunk is not is not splitting in a proper way. You need to understand how a file is constructed. Spend a couple days and write an MP4 parser. You will then understand how to split it correctly.

Comment: Saving the context may work. But it's a huge undertaking.